# Terminal command to return network class

Tags: terminal, command-line, network

I'm trying to construct myself a primitive network scanner, and I understand that there are multiple network classes and it has become necessary for my program to determine exactly what class of network the workstation is currently connected to.

I have trialled a few options which i consider to be needlessly complicated, such as truncating various commands such as `ifconfig`, however these methods are arduous and messy.

Is there a single Terminal command which can return simple output such as `10.0.0.0`, thereby identifying the network class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                   

IPS=$(ifconfig -a | perl -nle'/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/ && print $1' | sed 's/127.0.0.1//')

FIRST=$(echo "${IPS%%.*}")

case 1 in
$(($FIRST <= 127))) echo Class A ;;
$(($FIRST <= 191))) echo Class B ;;
$(($FIRST <= 223))) echo Class C ;;
$(($FIRST <= 239))) echo Class D ;;
$(($FIRST <= 255))) echo Class E ;;
*) echo Something wrong! ;;
esac
```

If You want only the IP, echo the `$IPS` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Please reconsider and reformulate your question.

You are mixing *[private IPv4 address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)* and *[classful networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network)* (which are deprecated or at least "old-fashioned" since 1993) and you don't consider *[classless networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)*.

In the old-fashioned concept of *classful networks* the leading bits 0 (Class A), 10 (Class B), 110 (Class C), 1110 (Class D) or 1111 (Class E) you get by issueing a proper `ifconfig` or `ipconfig` command **completely** determine the class.

So all IP-addresses starting with

- 0 - 127 belong to Class A
- 128 - 191 belong to Class B
- 192 - 223 belong to Class C
- 224 - 239 belong to Class D
- 240 - 255 belong to Class E

---

I can't add this as a comment because it's to long.

Answer (score 2):

With CIDR (Classless Inter Domain Routing) the old class concept is gone. Instead you create your networks by setting the proper subnetmask and your routing. So much for history. :-)

As my Yosemite outputs netmasks in ifconfig in hex, I wrote a shell script that analyses all ifconfig output and calculates the network from it. Maybe you could modify that to your needs. A sample output would be:

```
IP adress:      127.0.0.1 Netmask:      255.0.0.0 Network:      127.0.0.0
IP adress:   172.20.41.52 Netmask:  255.255.255.0 Network:    172.20.41.0
IP adress:    172.16.47.1 Netmask:  255.255.255.0 Network:    172.16.47.0
IP adress:   192.168.97.1 Netmask:  255.255.255.0 Network:   192.168.97.0
```

Here is the script; it omits inet6 adresses from ifconfig and relates only to IPv4:

```
#!/bin/sh

IP="`ifconfig -a | fgrep 'inet ' | sed -e 's/^.*netmask:\(.*\)$/\1/g' -e 's/^.*inet\ \([^\ ]*\)\ .*$/\1/'`"

convert_hex_netmask_to_dec () {
    nh=$1
    nd=$(($nh % 0x100))
    for i in 1 2 3
    do
        ((nh = nh / 0x100))
        nd="$((nh % 0x100)).$nd"
    done
    echo $nd
    # See more at: http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.shell/convert-hex-to-decimal/497395#sthash.ShzT161v.dpuf
    }

for ipadress in ${IP}
do
    netmaskhex="`ifconfig -a | fgrep 'inet ' | grep ${ipadress} | awk '{print $4}'`"
    netmaskdec="`convert_hex_netmask_to_dec ${netmaskhex}`"
    IFS=. read -r i1 i2 i3 i4 <<< "${ipadress}"
    IFS=. read -r m1 m2 m3 m4 <<< "${netmaskdec}"
    NET="`printf \"%d.%d.%d.%d\n\" \"$((i1 & m1))\" \"$(($i2 & m2))\" \"$((i3 & m3))\" \"$((i4 & m4))\"`"

    printf "IP adress:%15s Netmask:%15s Network:%15s\n" ${ipadress} ${netmaskdec} ${NET}
done
```

If you want only the first octet from the network, just disable the final printf and replace it with

```
printf "%d\n" "$((i1 & m1))"
```